# Scrolling within single div in Ionic

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working on my first Ionic application, and I've run across a problem getting scrolling to work within a single DIV. I've got a YouTube search functioning (code omitted from below because it isn't relevant - does not touch the div after injection or modify CSS), and it populates the youtubeDivSearch element with spans full of tables. However, no matter what I've tried, I can't get proper scrolling to work. I have tried setting the height of ion-scroll by getting the height of youtubeDivSearch after it is populated, but even though it sets the CSS property correctly, it seems to scroll an arbitrary amount down before firing the "bounce" effect that stops me from scrolling further, and without setting the height it simply bounces in place without any actual scrolling occurring.

I understand that "scrolling" + "ionic" have several questions, but I could not pinpoint a specific solution based on the questions I scoured and methods I've found on SO.

I am still familiarizing myself with the framework and AngularJS itself, so if there is a better method of achieving the scroll, I would love to know - but would also like to know why my current method isn't working I thought it was a timing issue - but the height calculation is NOT done in async - it is done after - and feels hacky to begin with so I'd like to change the method entirely.

My markup is below. Thanks.

```
<ion-view view-title="Video" hide-nav-bar="true">
<ion-content scroll="false">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
  <ion-scroll>
  <div id="youtubeDivSearch" class="list"></div> 
  </ion-scroll>
  </div>
</div>
 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: You can create a codepen?

Comment: Sure. Give me a few moments.

Comment: There's quite a bit of code/dependencies in the overall project, but here's a fair bit of it. Hope this is enough to describe the problem. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwRrWQ

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how your project and your weapon index.html but this would be the right way. You can edit the styles that I gave.

```
 <ion-scroll direction="y" style=" height: 500px">
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbQVgo)